# When I add firebase for flutter web My App will not run

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter-web

I was running my app smoothly. When I added firebase: ^7.2.1 to support the Flutter Web. Build for Web works fine but the build for Android always fails.

My Dependencies.

````
  flutter_timer: ^0.0.6
  http: any
  intl: ^0.16.1
  firebase: ^7.2.1 ```

---------------------------

These are Console message:



Launching lib/main.dart on SM G920L in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Invalid depfile: /Users/mac/Developer/Flutter/FlutterProjects/podio/.dart_tool/flutter_build/c4534ac7f6d60d954ed69c0226286dfd/kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: /Users/mac/Developer/Flutter/FlutterProjects/podio/.dart_tool/flutter_build/c4534ac7f6d60d954ed69c0226286dfd/kernel_snapshot.d

Compiler message:
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/top_level.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.1+1/lib/js.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;
^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.1+1/lib/js_util.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js_util'
export 'dart:js_util';
^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/auth.dart:306:25: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var nextWrapper = allowInterop((firebase_interop.UserJsImpl user) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/auth.dart:310:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => _changeController.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/auth.dart:340:25: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var nextWrapper = allowInterop((firebase_interop.UserJsImpl user) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/auth.dart:345:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((e) => _idTokenChangedController.addError(e));
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/database.dart:164:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseReference<T>'.
 - 'DatabaseReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((update) => jsify(transactionUpdate(dartify(update))));
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/database.dart:166:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseReference<T>'.
 - 'DatabaseReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var onCompleteWrap = allowInterop(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/database.dart:301:24: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var callbackWrap = allowInterop((database_interop.DataSnapshotJsImpl data,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/database.dart:325:30: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    jsObject.once(eventType, allowInterop(
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/database.dart:402:22: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DataSnapshot'.
 - 'DataSnapshot' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var actionWrap = allowInterop((d) => action(DataSnapshot.getInstance(d)));
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/messaging.dart:72:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((payload) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/messaging.dart:75:28: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/messaging.dart:87:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((payload) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/messaging.dart:97:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((_) => null);
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/messaging.dart:98:28: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/storage.dart:317:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'UploadTask'.
 - 'UploadTask' is from 'package:firebase/src/storage.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((storage_interop.UploadTaskSnapshotJsImpl data) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/storage.dart:321:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'UploadTask'.
 - 'UploadTask' is from 'package:firebase/src/storage.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => _changeController.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/storage.dart:322:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'UploadTask'.
 - 'UploadTask' is from 'package:firebase/src/storage.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var onCompletion = allowInterop(() => _changeController.close());
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/top_level.dart:194:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (js.hasProperty(error, 'message')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/top_level.dart:195:19: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
    var message = js.getProperty(error, 'message');
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:29:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'firestore') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:30:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'id') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:31:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'parent')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:37:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'latitude') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:38:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'longitude') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:44:15: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  var proto = util.getProperty(jsObject, '__proto__');
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:46:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(proto, 'toDate') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:47:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(proto, 'toMillis')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:52:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(proto, 'isEqual') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:53:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(proto, 'toBase64')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:67:24: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
    map[key] = dartify(util.getProperty(jsObject, key));
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:91:17: Error: Method not found: 'newObject'.
    var jsMap = util.newObject();
                ^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:93:7: Error: Method not found: 'setProperty'.
      util.setProperty(jsMap, key, jsify(value));
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:116:12: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    return allowInterop(dartObject);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:124:5: Error: Method not found: 'callMethod'.
    util.callMethod(jsObject, method, args);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:139:19: Error: Method not found: 'promiseToFuture'.
    value = await util.promiseToFuture(thenable);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:141:9: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
    if (util.hasProperty(e, 'code')) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:152:27: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
  return PromiseJsImpl<S>(allowInterop((
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:165:5: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    allowInterop(c.completeError);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:173:22: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get code => util.getProperty(_source, 'code');
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:176:25: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get message => util.getProperty(_source, 'message');
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:179:22: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get name => util.getProperty(_source, 'name');
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:182:32: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  Object get serverResponse => util.getProperty(_source, 'serverResponse');
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/utils.dart:185:23: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get stack => util.getProperty(_source, 'stack');
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/firestore.dart:105:30: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Firestore'.
 - 'Firestore' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var updateFunctionWrap = allowInterop((transaction) =>
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/firestore.dart:306:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentReference'.
 - 'DocumentReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((firestore_interop.DocumentSnapshotJsImpl snapshot) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/firestore.dart:310:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentReference'.
 - 'DocumentReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => controller.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/firestore.dart:445:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((firestore_interop.QuerySnapshotJsImpl snapshot) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/firestore.dart:449:24: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => controller.addError(e));
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/firestore.dart:775:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot'.
 - 'QuerySnapshot' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((s) => callback(DocumentSnapshot.getInstance(s)));
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.2.1/lib/src/interop/js_interop.dart:17:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'toDateString')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart:64:12: Error: Method not found: 'webOnlyInstantiateImageCodecFromUrl'.
    return ui.webOnlyInstantiateImageCodecFromUrl(resolved) as Future<ui.Codec>; // ignore: undefined_function
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:604:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:799:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:474:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:38:22)
#5      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:149:27)
#6      main (file:///b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:8:30)
#7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/mac/Developer/Flutter/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 801

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/mac/Developer/Flutter/SDK/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
````

When I run the Code before adding the web thing in flutter. It was working fine in Android. But When I added the firebase for web in flutter.
It stops working on Android and but working on Web fine.

Comment: Please post your `flutter doctor` response here as well...

Comment: having this issue for like almost 2 months... no soolution found yet..

Answer (score 3):

I found @davidmcharo's answer super helpful, but wanted to provide an update.

1) Firebase has a few packages that work with both mobile & web from a single codebase, but Realtime Database is not one. (as @Dazza5000 said.) I suggest using cloud_firestore instead.

2) Now that these packages support both mobile & web, you do not need to add the firebase dependency to your pubspec.yaml. This dependency is what causes the issues you described above. However, if you depended on it previously, simply running pub get after removing it from your pubspec.yaml will not get rid of this error. You have to navigate into the path that @davidmcharo described above (flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/) and remove the firebase-7.3.0 folder using his instructions. Once you do this, your mobile app should run.

3) There are a handful of articles out there detailing how to build a web & mobile cross-platform app using firebase, but they are quickly becoming outdated. I was able to get my app working WITHOUT using the kIsWeb global to specify a firebase package.

Another note: An issue I ran into was that I could get my mobile app working, but my web app continued to have issues until I removed Realtime Database from my app. I accidentally left a StreamProvider that accessed my old Realtime Database in the tree, and it prevented the web app from functioning correctly. Be wary of any lingering Realtime Database calls as you convert from RTB to Cloud Firestore.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase real-time database does not work across mobile and web - firestore, auth and a few others do.

You can find the firebase libraries that are supported across mobile and web here:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire

[image]

Comment: Which means, I have to remove firebase_database. If I want to use firebase with flutter web?

Comment: yes...or you can use the web version on web and the mobile version on mobile.

Comment: Okay!
But, What do you mean by web version / mobile version specifically!!
Can you explain a bit more!

Comment: @JEEALI he means that you'll have to develop two seperate flutter apps. One for iOS/Android that uses this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database and one for Flutter Web that uses this package: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase. You can quite easily share most of your codebase/widgets across both flutter apps though...(symlinks can be followed).

Comment: Absolutely not.. you build just one app with conditional imports..
that means a `Stub` file..a `Switcher` containing the method declarations only and the two different implementation files `WebRepository` file ( using `firebase` package ) and containing all the methods overrides for the web package, and the `DeviceRepository` containing the same methods overrides but for the Android/iOS `firebase_database` package. Plus I use a `Singleton` to initialise firebase when the `firebase` package is used ( WEB )..

Comment: I'll put an answer showing it all as soon as I fix one thing.. I just upgraded to the latest Flutter Stable channel and switched `firebase` package is now throwing weird errors complaining about `http import` and other stuff..

Comment: check out the whole process here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670753/flutter-firebase-realtime-database-in-web/61982735#61982735

Answer (score 1):

Firebase does not work for both web and mobile. You will have to have two separate projects, one for web which will have the firebase 7.2.1, and another project for mobile which will not have the firebase 7.2.1. So in order to make your mobile(android and iOS) work, you will have to uninstall or delete firebase 7.2.1 from your project. And if you wanna do that, do the following:

1.Go to your pubspec.yaml file, inside it under dependencies, remove firebase 7.2.1 or if you updated it to firebase 7.3.0 and you have both of those dependencies, remove both of them.

2.Then, use terminal to delete the folder firebase-7.2.1 and firebase-7.3.0 if you have both inside pub.dartlang.org. And how to delete it, is by opening terminal, then go to where your flutter folder, then inside the flutter folder go to .pub-cache by cd .pub-cache, then cd hosted, then cd pub.dartlang.org. This is the path for your path to pub.dartlang.org :  flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/. Then inside pub.dartlang.org, type the following command to delete the folder firebase-7.2.1, which is: rm -r firebase-7.2.1, and then rm -r firebase-7.3.0 if you have the folder firebase-7.3.0.

3. After deleting the firebase-7.2.1 and firebase-7.3.0 folders from step 2 above, then run flutter clean, and then run your app again using android or iOS emulator, and it should now be working fine.

Comment: I started using Firestore instead of realtime database.
It solves everything :)

Comment: @JEEALI if you only need packages that are available for both WEB and Device than you'r all sorted , but if instead you need to use some package ( as I do ) that is not yet supported, like `Remote Config` you'll have to use `firebase`. I'll put an answer to show the whole process later on..there is a little bit of boilerplate code to write but it works ..

Comment: Well.. actually you can check the whole process in my own answer here..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670753/flutter-firebase-realtime-database-in-web/61982735#61982735